# How to exclude folders/files from error-checking in Wolfram Workbench

Tags: workbench

I have subfolders in my project which contain version control files (GNU-RCS). Naturally some of the lines in these files aren't properly formed WL code and as a result, errors are generated.

Does anyone know how to switch off validation on specific folders/files?

I've already set the Derived property on the folder in question but this seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, figured it out.

1. Bring up the Properties window for your project.
2. Select Resources.
3. Select Resource Filters.
4. Add Filter
5. Check Exclude all.
6. Check Folders.
7. Check All children (recursive)
8. In Filter Details, set up how you want to exclude the folder in question. In my case it was Name Matches RCS, RCS being the name of the folder where the version control files are stored.

And that's it. The files will no longer be included in validation checks.